# Mac OS X Terminal - how do I "clear | java foo"?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, terminal, pipe

So I'm using the terminal and I issue the command

```
clear | java email11
```

And I get this crazy execution of half the code I wrote

> "Enter input filename [default: fileContainingEmails.txt]: Enter
>   output filename [default:  ]:"

then an error:

```
Enter input filename [default: fileContainingEmails.txt]: Enter output filename [default: 
]: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1516)
    at email11.main(email11.java:39)
```

all together like:

```
myMachine:mydir me$ clear | java email11
Enter input filename [default: fileContainingEmails.txt]: Enter output filename [default: 
]: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1516)
    at email11.main(email11.java:39)
```

and the termainal goes back to:

```
myMachine:mydir me$
```

So my question is, how do I pipe this command successfully?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? First command is used to clear the terminal and second one seems to require an input and an output file arguments, so they don't seem to be related.

Comment: You've shown us a command that doesn't work and described what it does.  You haven't told us what you *want* to do.  We can only make educated guesses about how to correct your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$ clear | xxd
```

which gives you something like

```
0000000: 1b5b 481b 5b32 4a                        .[H.[2J
```

This is the input to your email11 program. Probably not your intention.
Just do:

```
$ clear; java email11
```

That simply runs the two commands, one after the other, as if you had typed them on two separate lines.

You should probably read the documentation for the command shell you're using.  The default shell on OSX is bash; you can [see the manual here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html).

Comment: clear sends the ANSI ESC sequence to clear the terminal. See http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted to do

```
clear || java email11
```

Comment: This also works! Does || clear whatever was left in some buffer? What is happening when I use || ?

Comment: `||` executes the first command, then executes the second command only if if the first one succeeds.  It has nothing to do with buffering or I/O redirection.  Since the `clear` command normally won't fail (unless `$TERM` isn't set), I'm not sure why you'd use `||` rather than `;`.